# How to paste two strings with quotation signs?

Tags: r, string, paste

Let's say I have two columns in a dataframe, the first shows the codes of items; whereas the second shows the description, I want to construct a third that concatenates first two columns and displays in a format such as "1" = "soap" for the first row, and so on. Is it possible? Thanks in advance

I have tried something like c(""abc"", ""def"") and different variations of that format, none worked.

Comment: We need to escape the quotation mark: `c("\"abc\"", "\"def\"")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
transform(dat, x=sprintf('"%s"="%s"', a, b))
  a b       x
1 1 a "1"="a"
2 2 b "2"="b"
3 3 c "3"="c"
4 4 d "4"="d"
5 5 e "5"="e"
6 6 f "6"="f"

transform(dat, x = paste(shQuote(a), shQuote(b), sep='='))
  a b       x
1 1 a "1"="a"
2 2 b "2"="b"
3 3 c "3"="c"
4 4 d "4"="d"
5 5 e "5"="e"
6 6 f "6"="f"
```

Answer (score 0):

We may use `sprintf` in `Reduce`.

```
res <- Reduce(\(x, y) sprintf('"%s"="%s"', x, y), dat[c(1, 2)])
res
# [1] "\"1\"=\"a\"" "\"2\"=\"b\"" "\"3\"=\"c\"" "\"4\"=\"d\"" "\"5\"=\"e\"" "\"6\"=\"f\""
```

Looks weird, but just because internal storage method is shown. See if we `cat` it:

```
cat(res)
# "1"="a" "2"="b" "3"="c" "4"="d" "5"="e" "6"="f"
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- data.frame(a=1:6, b=letters[1:6], x=runif(6))
```